# Why wont <button type="submit"> work?

Tags: html, forms, submit-button

I have a standard HTML form, and the button is not working. I know it is directing to the correct page, and as far as I can see everything looks perfect.
It lets me click the button, but then nothing happens, it doesn't direct me to the `send.php` page or anything.

```
    <form method="post" action="http://www.URL.net/send.php">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="fBtn">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="regButton"><i class="icon-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Also, I have tried using `<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="regButton" value="Send Message" />` as well, but it also isn't working for some odd reason.

Tested in Chrome and IE11.

**EDIT** Here is the JS for form vaildation:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){ 

$('input#name').removeClass("errorForm");
$('textarea#message').removeClass("errorForm");
$('input#email').removeClass("errorForm");

var error = false; 
var name = $('input#name').val(); 
if(name == "" || name == " ") { 
    error = true; 
    $('input#name').addClass("errorForm");
}


    var msg = $('textarea#message').val(); 
    if(msg == "" || msg == " ") {
        error = true;
        $('textarea#message').addClass("errorForm");

    }

var email_compare = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i; 
var email = $('input#email').val(); 
if (email == "" || email == " ") { 
    $('input#email').addClass("errorForm");
    error = true;
}else if (!email_compare.test(email)) { 
    $('input#email').addClass("errorForm");
    error = true;
}

if(error == true) {
    return false;
}

var data_string = $('.contactForm form').serialize(); 


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('.contactForm form').attr('action'),
    data: data_string,

    success: function(message) {
            if(message == 'SENDING'){
                $('#success').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else{
                $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
            }
                }



});

return false; 
});
```

Comment: Your problem [isn't reproducible](http://jsfiddle.net/tqwm6ppx/)

Comment: Is there any JavaScript on the page?

Comment: @George, I updated the code, and it does work on the fiddle, it's just not working on my site.

Comment: @minitech, yes there is JS on the page.

Comment: Try to open the chrome console and see if sometimes there is some error.

Comment: I just read the console log, and this is the error i'm getting: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.trishajohnson.net/tj/send.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://trishajohnson.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @Trisha Are you using a Wordpress plugin for your form or did you create your own? It seems as JavaScript is preventing the default action, which is to submit the form.

Comment: Do you have any script that check for required fields?

Comment: @George No, this subdomain (/tj/) does not use wordpress, however the main domain (trishajohnson.net) does.

Comment: @Tim - yes there is, i will update my post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have some JavaScript that automatically submits every form using AJAX. Since you’re on the domain `trishajohnson.net`, the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents JavaScript from opening requests to a (slightly) different domain – `www.trishajohnson.net`.

There’s an easy fix, though – just use the path part. It’s cleaner anyway.

```
<form method="POST" action="/tj/send.php">
```

Comment: @Trisha: Throw jquery-migrate away. Use jQuery 1.11.2 or 2.1.3.

Comment: fixed console log errors, but button is still not working.. I am using 1.9.1 - I'll update and see if that resolves it. Updated, and still nothing.

Comment: I also removced the validation code to see if that would help, and IT WORKED!!! So, what is wrong with my validation code then?? hmmm...